# Assign an object to property using Object Literal Syntax

Tags: javascript, object-literal

I need to pass an object as property to other object using Object Literal Syntax, something like this:

```
var obj = functionReturnObject();
callOtherFunction({propertyName: obj});
```

I know there are other simple ways to do this, e.g.

```
var obj = functionReturnObject();
var auxObj= {};
auxObj.propertyName = obj ;
callOtherFunction(auxObj);
```

or

```
callOtherFunction({propertyName: functionReturnObject()});
//This way is not useful for me because I need to keep a copy of the object before use it as parameters to the function callOtherFunction()
```

I am wondering if there is any straight way to do this in literal syntax to avoid using an auxiliar object like auxObj

Comment: Your *something like this* is fine, whats wrong with `callOtherFunction({propertyName: obj});` ?

Comment: `callOtherFunction({propertyName: functionReturnObject()});` ??

Comment: Take a look to the comment below the second way. I need to keep a copy of the object before use callOtherFunction(). So I could do: 

`var obj = functionReturnObject();`
`callOtherFunction({propertyName: functionReturnObject()});`

but there is no good in performance because functionReturnObject() is a very heavy function.

Comment: @gsc-delmo Look at the first comment posted by Alex K. Use `var obj = functionReturnObject(); callOtherFunction({propertyName: obj});`

Comment: Sorry everybody, I was testing this issue in a wrong way in the browser. I will vote for your comments. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `auxObj`, just call like your sample:

```
callOtherFunction({
   propertyName: functionReturnObject(), 
   propertyAge: 20, 
   sex: 'M', 
   test: function() {
      // some process
      return 0;
   }   
});
```